# distribute nodes around the tree root with d3-hierarchy with animation

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I have the attached [a code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/znj3ykqwj3) showing my solution.

I feel my solution is not right as I have done all my calculations in the `NodesFanout` component.

```
import * as React from "react";
import NodeGroup from "react-move/NodeGroup";
import { StructureItem } from "../../types";
import { Node } from "../Node";
import { HierarchyPointNode } from "d3-hierarchy";
import { HierarchyLabelProps } from "../HierarchyLabel";
import { findIndex } from "lodash";
import { NodeHeight } from "../Tree";
import { findCollapsedParent } from "../../util/node";

const { Group } = require("@vx/group");

export interface NodesProps {
  nodes: HierarchyPointNode<StructureItem>[];
  clickHandler: any;
  shapeLength: number;
  collapse: boolean;
  Label: React.ComponentType<HierarchyLabelProps>;
  LabelCollapsed: React.ComponentType<HierarchyLabelProps>;
}

const positionNodes = (
  node: HierarchyPointNode<StructureItem>,
  nodes: HierarchyPointNode<StructureItem>[]
) => {
  let left: number;
  let top: number;

  if (!node.parent) {
    left = node.y / 2 - NodeHeight;
    top = node.x - NodeHeight;
  } else if (node.data && node.data.isRight) {
    const index = findIndex(nodes, node);
    const lastLeft = nodes[index - 1];

    top = lastLeft.x;
    left = NodeHeight;
  } else {
    top = node.x;
    left = node.y;
  }

  return {
    top: [top],
    left: [left],
    opacity: [1]
  };
};

export const NodesFanout: React.SFC<NodesProps> = ({
  Label,
  LabelCollapsed,
  nodes,
  shapeLength,
  clickHandler,
  collapse
}) => {
  return (
    <NodeGroup
      data={nodes}
      keyAccessor={(d: HierarchyPointNode<StructureItem>) => d.data.id}
      start={(node: HierarchyPointNode<StructureItem>) => {
        let left: number;
        let top: number;

        if (!node.parent) {
          left = node.y / 2 - NodeHeight;
          top = node.x - NodeHeight;
        } else {
          left = node.parent.y / 2;
          top = node.parent.x;
        }

        return {
          top,
          left,
          opacity: 0
        };
      }}
      enter={node => positionNodes(node, nodes)}
      update={node => positionNodes(node, nodes)}
      leave={node => {
        let left: number;
        let top: number;

        const collapsedParent = findCollapsedParent(
          node.parent
        ) as HierarchyPointNode<StructureItem>;

        if (!collapsedParent.parent) {
          left = collapsedParent.y / 2;
          top = collapsedParent.x - NodeHeight;
        } else {
          left = collapsedParent.parent.y / 2;
          top = collapsedParent.parent.x - NodeHeight;
        }

        return {
          top: [top],
          left: [left],
          opacity: [0]
        };
      }}
    >
      {nodes => (
        <Group>
          {nodes.map(({ key, data: node, state }, index) => {
            return (
              <Group
                top={state.top}
                left={state.left}
                key={key}
                opacity={state.opacity}
                className={`node__${index}`}
              >
                <Node
                  Label={Label}
                  LabelCollapsed={LabelCollapsed}
                  node={node}
                  shapeLength={shapeLength}
                  clickHandler={(e: any) => {
                    clickHandler({ e, node });
                  }}
                  key={key}
                  collapse={collapse}
                />
              </Group>
            );
          })}
        </Group>
      )}
    </NodeGroup>
  );
};
```

The animation is also not fanning out from the center correctly.

I am trying to achieve something like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/n3w687vmqj) where all the nodes spread out from the center.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Please share what animation do you exactly want.

Comment: @Root I have updated the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this achieves the goal: https://codesandbox.io/s/w4n1v3xvw

I don't think the code is problematic, its just the example you based on was one-sided, so the `leave` animation needed to be updated based on the side of each node.

This is the code changed with comments before changes:

```
leave={node => {
        let left: number;
        let top: number;
        let nodeIndex: number;

        const collapsedParent = findCollapsedParent(
          node.parent
        ) as HierarchyPointNode<StructureItem>;

        if (!collapsedParent.parent) {
          // Get this nodes index from its' position in the parent
          nodeIndex = findIndex(node.parent.children, node);

          // Even indices go one side and odd go to the other
          // So we add a modifier which changes sign based on NodeHeight
          let modifier: number = NodeHeight;
          if (nodeIndex % 2 == 1) {
            modifier *= -1;
          }

          // We add the modifier in the left calculation
          left = collapsedParent.y / 2 + modifier;
          top = collapsedParent.x - NodeHeight;
        } else {
          left = collapsedParent.parent.y / 2;
          top = collapsedParent.parent.x - NodeHeight;
        }

        return {
          top: [top],
          left: [left],
          opacity: [0]
        };
      }}
```

Comment: @dagda1 I don't see anything different in the animation from your sandbox and this answer sandbox, I'm using Chrome

Comment: @rioV8 You can see that before the nodes fade away on the collapse animation, they aren't exactly on top of the center node but somewhat around it. This is really apparent when viewing the minimized view, but also apparent in the full window if you look carefully. You can also change the opacity: [0] to opacity: [1] to see the problem in the original animation more carefully.

Comment: with `opacity[0]` there is no difference visible. with `opacity[1]` it is very hard to see an improvement.

Comment: [Here](https://i.imgur.com/avO24eH.png) is a screenshot from a few frames before the nodes disappear, on the left you see the initial situation and on the right the fixed one. Its quite obvious when you actually look for it that the nodes don't converge at the exact center. (And as I said the distortion depends on window size)